# C# : how to set another menu enabled

Tags: c#, menu, modifier

i want to create the following scenario

*when the user logged in successfully, some menu are opened*

and i have made the following code on `Login Button`

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isValid(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text))
        {
            main = new Main();
            this.Close();                
            main.isLoggedIn(true); //main is my Mdiparent form                                
            cmd.cetakSukses("Logged in successfully", title);
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.cetakGagal("Fill all the textbox !", title);
        }

    }
```

and here is the `isLoggedIn()` function

```
 public void isLoggedIn(bool status)
    {
        logoutToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = status;
        changePasswordToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = status;
        masterCoaToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = status;
        generalJournalToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = status;
        loginToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = !status;
    }
```

the form load function

```
private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isLoggedIn(false);
    }
```

the login form caller

```
private void logiunToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (login == null || login.IsDisposed)
        {
            login = new Login();
            login.MdiParent = this;
            login.Show();
        }
    }
```

Main.constructor code

```
 public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text= title;
        isLoggedIn(false);
    }
```

i am still wondering why does the menu is not enabled. is anybody know where did i go wrong ?

[image: the picture]

i am using visual c# 2008 on desktop application

Comment: because all this happens, THEN your page gets refreshed and everything  you changed is lost. You should check if your user is logged in upon page display and only then you can decide to change how your page is displayed.

Comment: Stupid me, several years of ASP.NET made me forget about all the other usages of .NET :-). My remark would in that case be totally out of scope indeed.

Comment: @Bartdude currently, i am developing desktop application, i dont use asp.net

Comment: @Cignitor do you set Enable property anywhere else? In Load event of your form (for example)?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti yep, i am using `isLoggedIn()` on the form_load , take a look at my updated thread for more detail. does it affect my code ?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti i have moved the code to the Main.Constructor, and it has no effect, i have attached the newer code

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti actually, when i run the project, the first shown is my `Main` form, the form contains 'login' menu, so i have to `loggedIn` first to set another menu enabled

Comment: So let's follow @Rephistorch's answer! If Main is your main MDI form then you don't need to create a new instance of it (and it won't ever be shown)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: After your clarification that this is a desktop app, and your posting of a code screenshot, I have a new recommendation.

Also, it looks as if you're using the login form as modal dialog.  Can you show us how this is laid out in the solution explorer and how the modal windows is being opened?

My final observation is that if you opened this modal window from your main form, you have to call back to the parent form in order to run that function.  When you create a new Main object, that object is entirely separate from the original caller.  I believe if you use main.Show(), you'll be able to see your new form.  I need to know how you're calling this login form to give you a specific recommendation.

Try performing ((Main)this.MdiParent).isLoggedIn(true) instead of instantiating a new Main object.

Clarification:
Replace

```
        main = new Main();
        this.Close();                
        main.isLoggedIn(true); //main is my Mdiparent form                                
        cmd.cetakSukses("Logged in successfully", title);
```

With this:

```
Main main = (Main)this.MdiParent;
main.isLoggedIn(True);
this.Close();
cmd.cetakSukses("Logged in successfully", title);
```

Comment: i am not using asp.net , i am developing desktop application now ,

Comment: i use `this.Close()` to close the login form and back to mdiparent form with some menu enabled. i don't know why does my code is not running well

Comment: Do no call this.Close() before the rest of your code is run.  Move this.Close() after you call the function on your Main form.

Comment: @Rephistorch it doesn't matter. Form won't be closed until method exits.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, Yeah I'm too used to ASP.NET as well I suppose.

Comment: i have added the code which i used to call `Login Form`, i don't think that it will access the enabled / disabled menu

Comment: @Rephistorch i cannot add the following code `((Main)this.MdiParent).isLoggedIn(true)` on my `Login Success` part of code

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Is there an error message?

Comment: Okay it works, where did i go wrong anyway ? since there's no error message shown

Comment: You were instantiating a brand new main form instead of using the main form that called the dialog window.

Any time you use the "new" statement, you're making a new version of that object.  If you want to use the existing version, you have to use the MdiParent object.